# finding records between two dates and without entries elsewhere

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a problem setting up my date boundaries for the query.

I want records between 10/1/2010 and 12/31/2010, but without a record (activity) in calendar year 2011 to date.

```
where INV.Date_Imported BETWEEN '10/1/2010' AND '12/31/2010'
    AND INV.RecID NOT IN (
        SELECT RecID 
        FROM [VW_Invoice_All] 
        WHERE Date_Imported > '1/1/2011' 
    )
```

Comment: And the query you have here isn't working because...?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? I don't recall if brackets are only quoted identifiers for SQL Server or if there are any other RDBMSs out there that use them.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what your exact logical problem is. This code is syntactically fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only glaring issues I see is your `Date_Imported` line. If you want 1/1/2011 to be included in the `NOT IN` query, you need to change the query to

```
WHERE Date_Imported >= '1/1/2011'
```

`BETWEEN` is already inclusive, which is what you appear to be going for.

Comment: my query is almost work but not 100%. i would like data in between ('10/1/2010' AND '12/31/2010) BUT not in 2011.

Comment: From what you've posted, your query should work with the one modification I've suggested. What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any times on your dates, but if they are `DATETIME` columns then that could be important. I would probably use:

```
WHERE
    INV.Date_Imported >= '10/1/2010' AND
    INV.Date_Imported < '1/1/2011' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [VW_Invoice_All] I2
        WHERE
            I2.RecID = INV.RecID AND
            I2.Date_Imported >= '1/1/2011')
```

(The `EXISTS` might give you better performance than the `IN` query, but test both.)

Answer (score 0):

As gtcompscientist says:

> BETWEEN is already inclusive...

so you only need:

```
WHERE INV.Date_Imported BETWEEN '2010-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 23:59:59'
```

To avoid any doubts, using the YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format means you don't need to worry about regional settings (UK dates are DD-MM-YYYY whilst US is MM-DD-YYYY but YYYY-MM-DD format is interpreted the same in both regions).

The addition of time (HH:mm:ss) ensures that you include all of 2010-12-31 i.e. from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the safest date format is 'yyyymmdd'. In the bank where I work at the moment it's the only format that works on both the production server and the test server.